# Custom validation doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, validation, custom-validators

I have a custom validitor in a webpage for a text area but it doesn't work !

I don't know why it is not working !!

Here is the code

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="comment" ErrorMessage="Your comment should be 100 letters or less" ForeColor="Black" ClientValidationFunction= "ClientValidate" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" ></asp:CustomValidator>

<script>

   function ClientValidate(source, arguments)
   {
      if (arguments.Value > 100)
         arguments.IsValid=false;
      else
         arguments.IsValid=true;
   }

</script>
```

and this is the code for server validation

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
            int commentlength = args.Value.Length;

            if (commentlength > 100)
            {
                args.IsValid = false;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                args.IsValid = true;
                return;
            }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Anyone can help me please!!

Comment: Is your code behind function getting called ? Put a breakpoint and check if it is hitting the code behind function. Also, check if you are receiving any error/exception in your code or in browser console inspect element.